# Pass parameter through constructor in generic constraints

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I want to pass parameter in constructor into generic function with constraints. Is it possible to create instance of `T` with parameters? Something like `list.Add(new T(1));`

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Base> list = new List<Base>();
        AddElement<Quick>(list,5);
        AddElement<Range>(list, 5); 
        Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static void AddElement<T>(List<Base> list, int number) where T : Base, new ()
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
       {
           //do not working
           list.Add(new T(i));
       }
    }
}
public abstract class Base
{

}

public class Quick:Base
{
    private int ID;
    public Quick()
    {

    }
    public Quick(int ID)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}

public class Range : Base
{
    private int ID;
    public Range()
    {

    }
    public Range(int ID)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way around this is to pass a factory method or `Func<T>` to the method:

```
public static void AddElement<T>(List<Base> list, int number, Func<T> factory) where T : Base
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        list.Add(factory());
    }
}
```

You can use that with your `Quick` class like this:

```
var baseList = new List<Base>();
AddElement(baseList, 5, () => new Quick(1));
```

If you wanted to be able to pass the `int` constructor argument inside `AddElement<T>()` you can use a `Func<int, T>` instead like so:

```
public static void AddElement<T>(List<Base> list, int number, Func<int, T> factory) where T : Base
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        list.Add(factory(i));
    }
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
var baseList = new List<Base>();
AddElement(baseList, 5, x => new Quick(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only do that with types (`T`) that have a constructor which takes *no arguments*.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

> The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor.